# Почему json_encode возвращает в Android null?

Tags: php, java, android, json

Привет. Подскажите. Есть код на Java для Android и на стороне сервера PHP

```
if ($r->num_rows > 0) {
$article=array();
while($row = $r->fetch_assoc())
{
    $article['id']=$row["id"];
    $imagejson = $row["images"];
    $image_obj = json_decode($imagejson);
    $article['image']=$image_obj->{"image_intro"};
    $res ="{"+"id:"+$row["id"]+"}";
}
```

}
else{
    echo "0 results";
}
$d->close();

$str =  utf8_encode(json_encode($article));
echo $str;

И есть код на Java.

```
class LoadPost extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        final TextView postText;
        StringRequest jsonObjectRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://app-container.ru/news-app/getPost.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                post_txt.setText(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Fail 2", error.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("id", id);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

    }
}
```

если в php прописать echo "something", то В приложении Выведется something.
Но если использовать json_encode, который в браузере всё хорошо выдаёт, то в приложении просто null. Подскажите что нибудь.

Comment: Дайте ссылку по которой в браузере всё ок, а в приложении `null`.